# Change path to folder storing icons for Leaflet Layer

Tags: leaflet, jquery

I have a Leaflet point layer that uses icons.  I have a different folder for individual time steps, and I would like to use a jquery ui slider to change between them.  Changing the slider should change the path used to define the markers on the layer.

This is my attempt thus far:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs
});

$( "#slider-bar" ).slider({
    value: 1999,
    min: 1999,
    max: 2014,
    step: 1,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        //console.log(ui);
    }
});

var markerPointLayer = L.geoJSON(britishColumbiaPoints, {

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'svg/1999/' + feature.properties.name + '.svg'
            })
        })
    },

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        $( "#slider-bar" ).on("change", function(feature) {
            layer.setIcon(L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'svg/' + $( "#slider-bar" ).slider("option", "value") + '/' + feature.properties.name + '.svg'
            }))
        })
    }

}).addTo(map);
```

But it seems that the onEachFeature function is not detecting that the slider bar has changed.

I've also tried doing this on the slider itself:

```
$( "#slider-bar" ).slider({
        value: 1999,
        min: 1999,
        max: 2014,
        step: 1,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            markerPointLayer.setIcon(
                L.icon({
                    iconUrl: 'svg/' + ui.value + '/' + markerPointLayer.feature.properties.name + '.svg'
                })
            )
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't recognize the layer object it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it myself.

First, the event for the jquery ui slider is not `change`, but rather `slidechange`.  Second, I needed to define an event listener on the jquery ui slider inside the onEachFeature function like so:

```
var markerPointLayer = L.geoJSON(britishColumbiaPoints, {

    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'svg/1999/' + feature.properties.name + '.svg'
            })
        })
    },

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

        $( "#slider-bar" ).on("slidechange", function(e) {
            layer.setIcon(L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'svg/' + $( "#slider-bar" ).slider("option", "value") + '/' + feature.properties.name + '.svg'
            }))

        })
    }

}).addTo(map);
```

Now, the layer is constantly listening to the jquery ui slider and will change each feature's icon accordingly whenever it changes.